# Activating conda env using shell script

Tags: bash, conda

Im trying to extract current working directory and activate conda environment using bash script. My shell script

```
app_path=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
source /conda/bin/activate $app_path;
```

This issue im facing is when I run the script as

```
sh script.sh
```

it is not activating the conda env

If i run with `source script.sh` 
It is not able to recognise readlink command. How to get both of them working together?

Comment: What does `not able to recognize readlink command` mean? An error message? Which one? Maybe all you need is to set a proper `PATH` in `script.sh` to include the directory where `readlink` lives.

Comment: I get an error "readlink" invalid option --b

Comment: Then show us the output of `sh -x script.sh`.